# How to make generic AsyncTask for Android Room request

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-asynctask, android-room

So I'm using Android Room library to perform requests on a SQLite DB.

I can't make requests on the UI thread, so I'm using AsyncTask.

My app is simple, I juste want to be able to insert new Users into my database.

So there is my UserDao.java :

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {
    @Insert
    long insert(User user);

    @Update
    void update(User user);

    @Delete
    void delete(User user);
}
```

And there is my User.java :

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // Getter / Setter
}
```

And then, to perform my Insert request, I have to make an entire AsyncTask class :

```
public static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<User, Void, User> {
        private WeakReference<Activity> weakActivity;
        private UserDao dao;

        // Constructeur
        insertAsyncTask(Activity activity, UserDao dao) {
            this.weakActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
            this.dao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(final User... params) {
            return this.dao.getById(this.dao.insert(params[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User u) {
            // Some code
        }
```

And finally, I'm calling the Insert like that :

```
new AppDatabase.insertAsyncTask(this, db.userDao()).execute(myUser);
```

So is it possible to make my AsyncTask class more generic ?
I would like to be able to use this class for multiple requests (like Insert, Update, Delete ...).

Or should I do a generic DAO instead ?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English ;)

Comment: You can use **thread** and **runnable** also for background task.

Comment: "so I'm using AsyncTask" -- I recommend using something more modern: `LiveData`, Kotlin coroutines, or RxJava.

Comment: Yeah, I looked LiveData and RxJava, but I don't understand how can they help me creating a single asynchronous task that can handle differents requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use it anywhere first you have to make generic Async task class for all methods
   You can create an interface, pass it to AsyncTask (in constructor), and then call method in onPostExecute()

```
    For example:
```

1.Your interface:

```
    public interface OnTaskRoomCompleted{
        void onTaskCompleted(User);
    }
```

2.Your Activity:

```
    public class YourActivity implements OnTaskRoomCompleted{
        // your Activity
    }
```

3.And your AsyncTask:

```
public class YourTask extends AsyncTask<User,Object,User>{ //change Object to required type
        private OnTaskRoomCompleted listener;

        public YourRoomTask(OnTaskCompleted listener){
            this.listener=listener;
        }

        // required methods
      protected void onPostExecute(Object user){
            // your stuff
            listener.onTaskRoomCompleted(user);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't really understand what is this method :
```Java
void onTaskCompleted(User);
```
I also can't understand how this can make "YourTask" more generic :/

Comment: Because I still need a "doInBackground()" function to perform my request.

Answer (score 0):

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

```
    UserId = view.findViewById(R.id.user_id);
    UserName= view.findViewById(R.id.user_name_id);
    UserEmail=view.findViewById(R.id.user_email_id);
    save = view.findViewById(R.id.bn_save);



    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String id = UserId.getText().toString();
            String name = UserName.getText().toString();
            String email =UserEmail.getText().toString();
           
            String userData[] ={id,name,email};
            GetUsersAsyncTask task = new GetUsersAsyncTask();
            try {
                String status = task.execute(userData).get();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),status , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           //emty the fields of the add user in the UI
            UserId.setText("");
            UserName.setText("");
            UserEmail.setText("");
        }
    });

}

private static class GetUsersAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String[], Void,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[]... strings) {
        String[] userDatas = strings[0];
        int id = Integer.parseInt(userDatas[0]);
        String name = userDatas[1];
        String email =userDatas[2];
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(id);
        user.setName(name);
        user.setEmail(email);
        MainActivity.myAppDatabase.myDao().addUser(user);
        return "Data Inserted SuccessFully....";
    }
}
```